# My form does not select image file

Tags: html, django

So far everything works well 
But the only problem i am facing is uploading imagefile..Image field does not import selected images .Please help and thanks

here is my model.py of my profile form

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):

   user = models.OneToOneField(User,unique=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   bio = models.TextField(max_length=500,null=True,blank=True)
   picture = models.ImageField(upload_to="profile_image",null=True)
   company = models.CharField(max_length=500,null=True)


   def __str__(self):
       return self.user.username

# Sending a new signal when ever a user is created to create a new profile
@receiver(post_save,sender=User)
def create_profile(sender,instance,created,**kwargs):
    if created:
       UserProfile.objects.create(user=instance)
```

And here is my view.py

```
@login_required
@transaction.atomic

def update_profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':

       profile_form = 
       ProfileForm(request.POST,instance=request.user.userprofile)
       if  profile_form.is_valid():

        profile_form.save()
        messages.success(request,'Your Profile has been Updated')
        return redirect('success:profile_account')
       else:
          messages.error(request,'fill out the fields correctly')
     else:

         profile_form = ProfileForm(instance=request.user.userprofile)
    return render(request,"success/user_account/edit_profile.html",
    {'profile_form':profile_form})
```

Here is the form.py

```
class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:

    model= UserProfile
    exclude=['user',]

    fields =['bio','picture','company']
```

And here is the hmtl file to render my updates

```
                <h4>{{ user.get_username }}</h4>
                <h4> {{ user.get_full_name}}</h4>
                <h4> {{ user.first_name}}</h4>
                <h4> {{ user.email}}</h4>
                <h4> {{ user.bio}}</h4>
                <h4> {{ user.userprofile.company }}</h4>SS
                <h4>{{user.userprofile.bio}}</h4>
                {% if user.userprofile.picture %}
                <image src="{{user.userprofile.picture.url}}" width="40" height="40">
                    {% else %}
                    <p> Chose a profile</p>
                    {% endif %}

                </image>
                <a href="{% url 'success:Profile_update' %} ">Update</a>
            </li>
```

And here is my Edit.html file

{% csrf_token %} {{ profile_form.as_p }} Save changes

Comment: Which is the problem, Image not saving to database or Image not showing in the template??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit your view,

```
def update_profile(request): 
    if request.method == 'POST':
        profile_form = ProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=request.user.userprofile) 
        if profile_form.is_valid():
            profile_form.save()
            messages.success(request,'Your Profile has been Updated')
            return redirect('success:profile_account')
        else: 
            messages.error(request,'fill out the fields correctly') 
    else: 
        profile_form = ProfileForm(instance=request.user.userprofile) 
    return render(request,"success/user_account/edit_profile.html", {'profile_form':profile_form})
```

You need to specify `request.FILES` in your form initialisation, inorder to upload files using Django forms.

Comment: This the error that occurred after editing the view.py .'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'Files'